# an algorithm that determines if a graph has a single MST

Tags: algorithm, minimum-spanning-tree, kruskals-algorithm, prims-algorithm

[image]

I think it has something to do with distinct edges yet i'm not sure how to prove it.

Answer (score 2):

In some way it's connected to distinct edges but that's not true that it's equivalent to have one MST and have distinct edges. (Exercise is to construct simple example)

**Hint**: suppose you have an MST. If there is one more MST then there's edge that you may add to MST (and remove some other(s)). How to check whether you can add specific edge?